# Cleanup of the packaging tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just started looking at our tags; I'm wondering if we can clean up some of the package-related ones. We currently have:

- [package-management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-management) (with an alias of [package-manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-manager))
- [packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages)
- [packaging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packaging)
- [package-conflicts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-conflicts)

as well as [apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt), [yum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yum), [rpm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpm), [packagekit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packagekit), and probably other tags for specific package managers.

I'd like to suggest that we:

- (merge?) [packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages) into [package-management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-management)
- remove [package-conflicts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-conflicts), as those questions should deal with a specific package manager

**EDIT** to clarify my suggestions for changes:

- Merge [packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages) and [package-conflicts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-conflicts) into [package-management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-management).
- Keep the package-specific tags (e.g. [apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt), [yum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yum), etc).
- I'm in favor of removing [packaging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packaging) as it would commonly relate to a specific package manager. Not opposed to keeping it for general packaging questions, though (pros/cons of RPM vs DEB; how do I avoid filename conflicts).

Comment: No, `packaging` and `package-management` are two very different things. A developer creating a package would use `packaging` and a user installing one would use `package-management`. Questions about building a package should be tagged with both `packaging` _and_ the package manager's tag as appropriate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything in your first four points can be merged into [package-management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-management), but specific package manager tags ([apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt), [yum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yum)) and package format tags ([rpm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpm), [deb](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deb)) should stay as-is.

Specific package manager tags needs to stay as-is because they behave differently in some cases, and package format tags because I could ask a question about creating and installing packages independent of the package manager.

---

**EDIT**

As @FaheemMitha says, [packaging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packaging) should remain to indicate questions about creating/dismantling packages, of course with a proper description indicating so.

Comment: Upvoted, but 'packaging' should probably be separate. That's for people who are trying to write it, I think.

Comment: I upvoted both this answer and the question, with the same caveat as @FaheemMitha - that packaging should remain.

Answer (score 4):

I think:

- "packages" should definitely be folded in to "package-management".
- "packaging" should definitely *not* be folded in; I've just proposed a tag wiki edit based on my understanding of that tag (for packag*ing*, not the end user's experience with packages).  (It also seems to me that a software developer would want to make packages for multiple distros where possible, but maybe that is harder than I think.)
- "package-conflicts" seemed at first glance to be a valid tag, but when I checked it only has 8 questions tagged, and the majority of those seem like they should just be tagged with "software-installation".  So given the sparse use of the tag, I say yes, it could be removed without loss.