# Overlap between "software-installation" and "package-management"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There has been recent effort by a new community member to tag (in particular old) questions related to software installation with the [software-installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-installation) tag. Since this also includes questions already tagged as [package-management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-management) (see [this example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/363822)), I wonder how much these tags overlap and in what situations it is reasonable to have both present on a question.

Comment: There's some [history of the package-management tag](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3692/cleanup-of-the-packaging-tags) here that I'd like to link in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I saw those edits today, and wondered the same thing -- thank you for bringing it up on Meta for discussion!

IMHO, [package-management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-management) covers both the *installation* and the *removal* aspects (besides updates and searching & etc). Unfortunately, I think it would be a bit of a stretch to use [package-management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-management) for tarball-type installs.

I could see keeping [software-installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-installation) exclusively for "manual" installation (via `make install`, for example) and using [package-management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/package-management) when there's a higher-level program involved (`yum`, `apt`, etc).

Comment: I do wonder a bit about the package management tag in the face of existing package manager tags (`yum`, `rpm`, `apt`, etc), but that's a discussion for another day.

Comment: Yeah, I wondered about that point too in the past ...

Comment: it's never a bad thing to have a general tag and a precise one, it allows for asking general questions about things and precise question about something specific.

Comment: The software installation was meant for a catch all that didn't fit with the most specific tags, like the specific package managers. For package managers, I prefer not having a general tag for all of them, since each has their own name and set of quirks.